# Twig3: How to migrate "for item in items if item.foo == 'bar'" with loop bariable

Tags: symfony, twig

I use the following Twig 2 code:

```
{% for item in items if item.foo == 'bar' %}
   <span class="{% if loop.index % 2 %}special-class{% endif %}">
       {{ item.value }}
   </span>
{% else %}
    Nothing found
{% endfor %}
```

In the twig docs: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html

> Adding an if condition on a for tag is deprecated in Twig 2.10. Use a `filter` filter or an "if" condition inside the "for" body instead (if your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop)

I wonder how I migrate my Twig 2 code to Twig 3. As you see I use the loop variable and `else` in the for loop. I know that I can use a new parameter and increase it myself... but it that really the intention? How do I rewrite this code using `filter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `filter` filter your code would look something like this (see also https://twigfiddle.com/9hiayc and https://twigfiddle.com/9hiayc/2):

```
{% for item in items|filter(i => i.foo == 'bar') %}
   <span class="{% if loop.index % 2 %}special-class{% endif %}">
       {{ item.value }}
   </span>
{% else %}
    Nothing found
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: looks like @DarkBee was faster

Answer (score 4):

You have two options to solve this

1. Place the `if`-tag inside the loop

```html
{% set i = 0 %}
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.foo == 'foo' %}
        <span class="{% if i % 2 %}special-class{% endif %}">
            {{ item.value }}
        </span>
        {% set i = i + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    Nothing found
{% endfor %}
```

*With this solution you can't "rely" on the internal `loop` variable, as the counter keeps going up whether or not the condition was met*

2. Use the `filter` - filter

```html
{% for item in items | filter(item => item.foo == 'foo') %}
   <span class="{% if loop.index % 2 %}special-class{% endif %}">
       {{ item.value }}
   </span>
{% else %}
    Nothing found
{% endfor %}
```

[updated demo](https://twigfiddle.com/0mqsgl/3)

Comment: Option 1 does not work because of the loop index. It will not mark every second span with the "special-class". See https://twigfiddle.com/0mqsgl 

But the option 2 is working. Thank you